# Scope of variable initialised in viewDidLoad to another method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In the view did load I have this segment:

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
```

Which works fine,

However further down in: `webViewDidFinishLoad` I have:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

And the scope of spinner has been lost. I have not got spinner as an outlet or a property / synthesised - still getting to grips with it. I think once I get the handle over the scope, it should make obj-c ability better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And the scope of spinner has been lost.

`spinner` is a *local* variable. It disappears as soon as the code reaches the nearest closing curly brace following its declaration. If you don't want it to happen, make `spinner` an instance variable of the class or the class extension.

Instance variables are declared inside curly braces following the interface declaration or the class extension declaration, for example:

```
// In the header file...
@interface MyClass {
    ...
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
}
...
@end
```

or

```
// In the implementation file...
@interface MyClass() /*class extension*/ {
    ...
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
}
...
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Thanks so much for this, will accept when it lets me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the spinner an instance variable in the header file, otherwise `webViewDidFinishLoad` won't be able to see that variable.

Answer (score 0):

In you viewDidLoad set a tag for spinner

```
  spinner.tag = 90;
```

and in webViewDidFinishLoad method use the following line

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *activity =(UIActivityIndicatorView *) [self.view viewWithTag:90];
 [activity stopAnimating];
     or  declare spinner in .h file so that you can use it any where.
```